# Get lazy but reusable cursor with Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, pygresql

I saw in [the docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) that you need to use server-side ("named") cursors to avoid loading all results into memory at once.  But then I found that server-side cursors aren't reusable.  You can only do a single `.execute` on them.  (Otherwise you get `ProgrammingError: can't call .execute() on named cursors more than once`.)

Is there any way to get a cursor that I can re-use, but that also will not load all the data into memory at once?

I'm open to using a different Postgres driver if it will make things easier and more performant.  I looked at PyGreSQL but it seems noticeably slower than a Postgres named cursor.

Comment: As the question is it is a long answer. Please narrow it down. You mean the Python side processing is expensive so you close the cursor (and the connection) while doing it? Did you consider [`with hold`?](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors). Did you consider Postgresql side processing in instead?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I just want a cursor object so that I can do `cur.execute(...)`, and when I do that it will not load all the results into memory at once.  Then after I process them by iterating over the cursor, or using `fetchone` or whatever, I want to be able to call `cur.execute(...)` again on the same cursor object.  Will `with hold` accomplish that?

Comment: Do `execute` only once. From then on just `fetch` from the cursor.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: What if I want to do multiple queries?

Comment: Use a different cursor for each query. That's why I asked you to narrow the question down.

Comment: If you will do multiple queries and combine them in Python then it is likely wrong.

Comment: Is that the only option?  It's just a pain to have to recreate cursors everywhere, instead of passing one cursor around.

Comment: create a wrapper, I have that for my PG query so I don't have to recreate it everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

Just don't reuse the cursors. Reuse the connections.